# samsung api how to call

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, accelerometer

does anyone knws how do i call it?
public struct SmiAccelerometerVector
        {
            public float x;
            public float y;
            public float z;
        }

i want to get the x,y,z values and paste it into a label.

Comment: for what kind of device?

Comment: Samsung Omnia with accelerometer, haptics

Comment: It is still C++.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696221/in-using-samsung-acclerometer

Comment: i'm coding on Vs2008 C#... anyhelp appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks ctacke i got it already. Here it is :)

```
    private void GetVectorHandler(Accelerometer.Vector accel) 
    { 
        if (Accelerometer.GetVector(ref accel) == SmiResultCode.Success) 
         {
             yy = accel.y.ToString();
             xx = accel.x.ToString();
             zz = accel.z.ToString();
         } 
    }
```

after that we need to do this, inside form_load or wadeva

```
            GetVectorHandler(gVector);
            lblX.Text = "x: " + xx;
            lblY.Text = "y: " + yy;
            lblZ.Text = "z: " + zz;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Samsung's documentation](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/onlinedocs/cmsCnts/20091105/0526/0526.html) is unclear on the exact DLL that contains these functions, but I believe it would look like this:

```
public struct Vector 
{
    Single X;
    Single Y;
    Single Z;
}

[DllImport("SmiSDK.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int SmiAccelerometerGetVector(out Vector vector);
```